# Is there a way to mass reduce prices of specified products? And their tier pricing too?

Tags: shipping, database, price, mysql, tierprice

We have a live catalogue of just over 125,000 products currently.

We are looking to reduce the selling price of all products that sell for £78.99 or less by exactly £5.00. We’ll then be adding a £4.95 delivery charge for these products at checkout.

If an order total comes to £79.00, we’ll offer free delivery. But we need to discount the selling price by £5.00 for any product equal or less than £78.99 to allow the overall total to be the same for these products. The delivery charge the customer's pay us is to be £4.95. (Catchier than £5.00).

But I still want the selling prices of our items to remain as whole numbers, which is why list and special prices are coming down by a whole £5.00. Hope this makes sense?

The fun doesn't stop here, the tier pricing for all products needs to move accordingly too......

Not sure if there is a really simple way to do this?

We've tried the running the below thus far:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once('app/Mage.php');

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$deliveryCharge = 4.95;
$threshold = 78.99;
$subtract = 5;

$count = 0;

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('grand_total', array('lteq' => $threshold))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('shipping_amount', 0);

foreach ($orders as $order)
{
    $count++;

    $currentPrice = 0;
    $currentItem = null;
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item)
    {
        if ($item->getPrice() > $currentPrice)
        {
            $currentPrice = $item->getPrice();
            $currentItem = $item;
        }
    }

    $currentItem->setBasePrice($currentItem->getBasePrice() - $subtract / $currentItem->getQtyOrdered());
    $currentItem->setPrice($currentItem->getPrice() - $subtract / $currentItem->getQtyOrdered());
    $currentItem->setBaseRowTotal($currentItem->getBaseRowTotal() - $subtract);
    $currentItem->setRowTotal($currentItem->getRowTotal() - $subtract);
    $currentItem->setBaseRowTotalInclTax($currentItem->getBaseRowTotalInclTax() - $subtract);
    $currentItem->setRowTotalInclTax($currentItem->getRowTotalInclTax() - $subtract);

    try
    {
        $currentItem->save();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {

    }

    $order->setBaseShippingAmount($deliveryCharge);
    $order->setShippingAmount($deliveryCharge);
    $order->setBaseShippingTaxAmount($order->getBaseShippingAmount() - $order->getBaseShippingAmount());
    $order->setShippingTaxAmount($order->getShippingTaxAmount() - $order->getShippingTaxAmount());
    $order->setBaseSubtotal($order->getBaseSubtotal() - $subtract);
    $order->setSubtotal($order->getSubtotal() - $subtract);

    try
    {
        $order->save();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {

    }
}

echo "Updated {$count} orders.";

?>
```

Then followed by after the above has ran:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once('app/Mage.php');

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$count = 0;

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();

foreach ($orders as $order)
{
    if ($order->getTaxAmount() > 0)
    {
        continue;
    }

    $count++;

    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item)
    {
        $item->setTaxPercent(20);
        $item->setTaxAmount($item->getBaseRowTotal() - $item->getBaseRowTotal() / 1.2);
        $item->setBaseTaxAmount($item->getBaseRowTotal() - $item->getBaseRowTotal() / 1.2);

        $item->setBasePrice($item->getBasePrice() / 1.2);
        $item->setPrice($item->getPrice() / 1.2);
        $item->setBaseOriginalPrice($item->getBaseOriginalPrice() / 1.2);
        $item->setOriginalPrice($item->getOriginalPrice() / 1.2);
        $item->setBaseRowTotal($item->getBaseRowTotal() / 1.2);
        $item->setRowTotal($item->getRowTotal() / 1.2);

        try
        {
            $item->save();
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {

        }
    }

    $order->setBaseShippingTaxAmount($order->getBaseShippingAmount() - $order->getBaseShippingAmount() / 1.2);
    $order->setShippingTaxAmount($order->getShippingTaxAmount() - $order->getShippingTaxAmount() / 1.2);
    $order->setTaxAmount($order->getBaseGrandTotal() - $order->getBaseGrandTotal() / 1.2);
    $order->setBaseSubtotal($order->getBaseSubtotal() / 1.2);
    $order->setSubtotal($order->getSubtotal() / 1.2);

    try
    {
        $order->save();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {

    }
}

echo "Updated {$count} orders.";

?>
```

But this hasn't achieved the expected results. Not even close in fact.... I haven't got to the point of tackling the movement of all the tier products pricing as yet.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you modifying existing order items?

Comment: you can use promotions->catalog price rule for apply £5.00 to every products.

Comment: Hi @benmarks, we want to make our prices appear more competitive in shopping comparison sites for low value items. We find very few people purchase low value items from us. For example we have an item for sale at £20. Other stores may have the item priced at around £15 + shipping. So at £20 with free delivery, we don't get a look in. I perhaps didn't explain this particularly well. We currently offer free shipping on every item.

Comment: Hi @DRAJI we're aware of the catalog price rule feature for Magento, we use it quite heavily already. We're looking to reduce the selling price of all items under a certain value though. So it is the special price of each item we want to reduce. Using catalog price rule won't display the lower prices to shopping comparison sites etc.

Comment: My point is that you are loading an order item collection. Order Items have already been purchased.

Comment: Gotcha! Your right. I'll remove references to the order item collection and see how that runs. How does the rest of the code look?

Comment: $product->setSpecialPrice( ($product->getSpecialPrice()-5)); Tr this code with product collections